# MySQL: update field only if condition is met

Tags: sql, mysql, if-statement, sql-update

Is it possible to do UPDATE query on MySQL which updates field value only if certain condition is met? Something like this:

```
UPDATE test
SET
    CASE
        WHEN true
        THEN field = 1
    END
WHERE id = 123
```

In other words, "field" would be only updated if condition is met, otherwise nothing is done.

**UPDATE**: my example query didn't exactly specify my problem in full, because there might be more fields to be updated without conditions, in other words:

```
UPDATE test
SET
    something = 1,        /*field that always gets updated*/
    CASE
        WHEN true
        THEN field = 1    /*field that should only get updated when condition is met*/
    END
WHERE id = 123
```

Sorry for the lack of info.

Comment: The only reason to use case in the update query is if you want to update the rows differently depending on a condition. If you just want to update some rows, just add the conditions to the where clause.

Answer (score 167, accepted):

Yes!

Here you have another example:

```
UPDATE prices
SET final_price= CASE
   WHEN currency=1 THEN 0.81*final_price
   ELSE final_price
END
```

This works because MySQL doesn't update the row, if there is no change, [as mentioned in docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html):

> If you set a column to the value it currently has, MySQL notices this
>   and does not update it.

Comment: "field" would be only updated if condition is met, **otherwise nothing is done.**

Comment: Yes! Exactly what I want it to do.

Comment: What about `WHERE currency=1`?

Comment: It is also a good way. In fact I did not post the whole command I am using, that involves the update of other fields.
Just wanted to post this to show the use of `WHEN` in an `UPDATE` query.

Comment: @fedorqui As your query looks like right now you will update the rows where current != 1 as well, to the same value as it already has. This could fire update triggers and have other effects like updating "ON UPDATE" `TIMESTAMP` columns.

Comment: Looks like this option works best for me, because it would still update other fields in the query.

Comment: @fedorqui, I took the liberty of updating your answer with a documentation reference of why this actually works.

Comment: @radoh and I thank you very much for such improvement! This is in fact good to know for the case of triggers that [someone mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14893355/mysql-update-a-field-only-if-condition-is-met/14893412?noredirect=1#comment20886578_14893412) a while ago.

Comment: I tried this without the `ELSE final_price`. This caused the rows where `currency!=1` to become empty. The original values, whatever they may be, were erased. Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 51):

Another solution which, in my opinion, is easier to read would be:

```
UPDATE test 
    SET something = 1, field = IF(condition is true, 1, field) 
    WHERE id = 123
```

What this does is set 'field' to 1 (like OP used as example) if the condition is met and use the current value of 'field' if not met.  Using the previous value is the same as not changing, so there you go.

Comment: Yes, I agree, this is much more beautiful looking, and also is the format I noticed mysql workbench syntax's it too. I personally think that this should be the common practice syntax for this query.

Answer (score 13):

Try this:

```
UPDATE test
SET
   field = 1
WHERE id = 123 and condition
```

Comment: I downvoted this again... as that is not even remotely a solution to the problem... it puzzles me how people seem to have upvoted this

Comment: @Dominique, Maybe you have confused by error on word `condition`?

Comment: the problem with the WHERE condition is that it acts on the row level and not on the field level. If you have an update of few fields and you want a condition on one of them only then the WHERE will not work. It will either cause the row to be update or not, affecting the other fields as well.

Comment: I don't have you confused with anything, I just know that your suggestions is completely wrong and not what the OP asked.  You should read the question again

Comment: @Dominique , I saw that the answer get a lot downvotes and decided to discover the problem. As an developer with analytical thinking I had a look on edits of original post, and voila, this answer is exact for what was asked initially.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution we can use MySQL `IF()` conditional function :

```
UPDATE test
SET  field  = IF(something == 1{CONDITION}, 1 {NEW VALUE}, field)
WHERE `id` = 5
```

Comment: `UPDATE servers SET port = IF(port != 21, 22, port) WHERE \`id\` = 123;` in my case i want to set ssh port to 22 if not only 21 telnet port else leave 22

Comment: Shouldn't it be single equals not double equals?

Answer (score 3):

Another variation:

```
UPDATE test
SET field = IF ( {condition}, {new value}, field )
WHERE id = 123
```

This will update the `field` with `{new value}` only if `{condition}` is met

Comment: This answer is also much better than the accepted one!

Comment: okay i find this a great answer, though what would happen to performance, if this particular field is continuously updated

Answer (score -2):

found the solution with AND condition:

```
  $trainstrength = "UPDATE user_character SET strength_trains = strength_trains + 1, trained_strength = trained_strength +1, character_gold = character_gold - $gold_to_next_strength WHERE ID = $currentUser AND character_gold > $gold_to_next_strength";
```