# Conditional UPDATE in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I am trying to `UPDATE` values from a table, but I need to add some conditions. I found the function `CASE`, but I am not if it is the best method.

Here is an example. My table is 'relation':

```
userid1 | userid2 | name1 | name2
```

I got for example:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM relation 
WHERE (userid1 = 3 AND userid2 = 4)
      OR (userid1 = 4 AND userid2 = 3);
```

Output:

```
4 | 3 | bill | jack
```

and I want to change the name of the user 3 in the relation between 3 and 4, but I don't know if it is the `userid1` or the `userid2`.

I thought of case:

```sql
UPDATE relation 
   CASE WHEN userid1 = 3 THEN SET name1 = 'jack' END 
        WHEN userid2 = 3 THEN SET name2 = 'jack' END 
WHERE (userid1 = 3 AND userid2 = 4) 
      OR (userid1 = 4 AND userid2 = 3);
```

But it doesn't work! Any ideas?

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35082542/3063226

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not very clear what you want to get in the end, but here is how you could correctly use conditional `SET` in your `UPDATE`

```sql
UPDATE relation 
   SET name1 = CASE WHEN userid1 = 3 THEN 'jack' ELSE name1 END,
       name2 = CASE WHEN userid2 = 3 THEN 'jack' ELSE name2 END
WHERE (userid1 = 3 AND userid2 = 4) 
   OR (userid1 = 4 AND userid2 = 3);
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/69074/1)** demo.

Comment: Thanks much for your help, I am testing it right now, I keep you in touch.
PS: I saw your formating improvement I will keep this in mind for further post

Comment: @peterm I am also looking at this problem and this method cannot prevent the increment of the affectedRows in the returned result which I want to use to confirm if its a success update or failure update due to outdated values.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35082542/3063226 is much better solution!

Answer (score 9):

I know I'm a little late to this, but I think an easier to read solution would be to use the IF() function in MySQL:

```
UPDATE relation
    SET name1 = IF(userid1 = 3, 'jack', name1),
        name2 = IF(userid2 = 3, 'jack', name2)
WHERE (userid1 = 3 AND userid2 = 4) 
   OR (userid1 = 4 AND userid2 = 3);
```

The IF function is used like this:

```
IF(condition, value_if_true, value_if_false)
```