# mysql update on condition of another field

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a property table where it updates from an XML feed regulary. If the property is not in the database it inserts; if it is there it updates it. But also users can update the fields via a form on the back end of the website. If a user updates a field, it flags it up and changes the status to 1.

My table looks like this:

```
heading    | nice house  
up_heading |    1  
price      |  40000  
up_price   |    0
```

In this case, when daily cron job runs the update, it will not update the heading as the `up_heading`'s status is 1, but it will update the price as the status of `up_price` is 0.

So my question is, how can I write an efficient update query like:

```sql
update property
set heading = $heading
case up_heading = 0, set price = $price
case up_price   = 0,
```

and so on till `where p_id = %p_id`?

Comment: This is what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17265522/conditional-update-in-mysql

Comment: What I would do is use PHP in the cron job script to parse the fields and set necessary data, then run a simple UPDATE sql statement with a WHERE clause and avoid conditions in the query.

Comment: `set heading = $heading` < that is missing a comma btw, should that be part of your real code.

Comment: this is my code at the moment   if($up_p_advert_heading == 0){$update_p_advert_heading  = "p_advert_heading = '$p_advert_heading',";}          else{ $update_p_advert_heading  = "";}
   if($up_p_postcode   == 0){$update_p_postcode   = "p_postcode   = '$p_postcode', p_lon = '$p_lng', p_lat =  '$p_lat', ";} else{$update_p_postcode      = "";}                          
   if($up_p_price    == 0){$update_p_price    = "p_price    = '$p_price', p_price_numeric = '$p_price_numeric',";}  else{$update_p_price       = "";}

Comment: please don't dump code in comments, update your question http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37032762/edit

Answer (score 1):

```sql
update property set
    heading = case when up_heading = 0 then $heading else heading end,
    price   = case when up_price   = 0 then $price   else price end
    -- and so on
where p_id = %p_id
```

[Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case)