# How can I fill empty cells with values from previous rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that looks like the following example. I'd like to replcae the missing value (if any) in a column with the previous value. So for this table:

```
 col1      col2    

 0.1       0.2
 0.23      0.53
  -        0.46
 0.77       - 
   -       0.32
```

I would expect the following results:

```
 col1      col2

 0.1       0.2
 0.23      0.53
 0.23      0.46
 0.77      0.46 
 0.77      0.32
```

Comment: Can you clarify what the order is here? I can't determine if you're ordering by col1 in ascending order or not. In a proper database design, the order of rows shouldn't matter. I think this is doable, but it needs to be more clear what the "previous value" is, and what defines that previous value, not just how you see it visually.

Answer (score 0):

Without some other field in the table, there is no inherent ordering to determine which is "previous"; if it were some sort of value sequence, maybe something could be done, but your final row of 0.32 indicates otherwise.

This very unreliable script *might* work for you...

```
SET @a := 0;
SET @b := 0;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `tmp`
SELECT @a := IFNULL(col1, @a) AS col1, @b := IFNULL(col2, @b) AS col2
FROM the_table
;
TRUNCATE TABLE the_table;
INSERT INTO the_table (col1, col2)
SELECT col1, col2
FROM tmp
;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE `tmp`;
```

Note: that all is if you want to update the values in the table; if you just want a resultset that does this, just the `SELECT` used in the `CREATE` would suffice.

Note2: this is unreliable because it may return different results on the "same" data depending on a number of factors, such as: ENGINE used for the table, or history of the table (if the "last" record was inserted after some rows were deleted, it may end up in the position of an "earlier" row that was deleted).

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but I think this should be a comment (like the one I've left). As it is, you are right that it cannot be done, but I suspect clarification can be given to help make this possible.

Comment: I'll add a very unreliable answer as well. ;)

Comment: There is no such way to determine the next value in this case. Just need to copy the above value if any field is missing

Comment: Thanks a lot @Uueerdo...i'l try with this

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this, you'll need some sort of identifier for the previous row. Hypothetically (since I am waiting for clarification on 'previous' in your example), let's say you have a primary key identifier for each row:

```
| id | col1 | col2 |
+----+------+------+
| 1  | 0.1  | 0.2  |
| 2  | 0.23 | 0.53 |
| 3  | null | 0.46 |
| 4  | 0.77 | null |
| 5  | null | 0.32 |
```

You can use the value from the previous primary key to update the table. You can `JOIN` the two tables on the condition that the id matches the previous one, and set the col1 value accordingly like this:

```
UPDATE myTable m
JOIN myTable mt ON (m.id - 1) = mt.id
SET m.col1 = mt.col1 WHERE m.col1 IS NULL;
```

To do this for both columns in the same update query, you'll need to add an `IF` statement:

```
UPDATE myTable m
JOIN myTable mt ON (m.id - 1) = mt.id
SET m.col1 =
  CASE WHEN m.col1 IS NULL THEN
    mt.col1
  ELSE
    m.col1
  END,
  m.col2 = 
  CASE WHEN m.col2 IS NULL THEN
    mt.col2
  ELSE 
    m.col2
  END;
```

Here is another [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14893355/mysql-update-a-field-only-if-condition-is-met) on the conditional update, and an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/157a0) example. Currently I can't run the query, just the build schema option. I will edit this answer with the results when I can.

Note that this will not work if there are two null values in a row. If that is possible, you will need to join the rows on the most recent non-null id.

Comment: @ita I'm glad I could help. If this works, feel free to accept the answer by clicking the checkmark next to the answer so future readers will know what solved your problem.

Comment: I'l definitely accept the answer which would help me solve my problem