# MySQL - Set whichever column is equal to a value

Tags: mysql, sql, conditional-statements

I have ten columns called image1, image2...image10, I want to update the value of one column to a new value, but it must only update the one column which is equal to the value I supply.

For example lets the supplied value is 1, and I want to change it to a string such as "C:/folder/subfolder".

I was thinking is there some if statement such as "if image1 = 1 set image1 = "C:/folder/subfolder" else if image2 = 1 set image2 = "C:/folder/subfolder", etc?

Comment: First, read [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html) and maybe browse around [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/retrieving-data.html).

Comment: In a stored procedure, yes.

Comment: A similar question was found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14893355/mysql-update-a-field-only-if-condition-is-met)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `IF` expression. If it matches the supplied value, you return the new value, otherwise you return the old value (so it has no effect on that column).

```
UPDATE tableName
    SET image1 = IF(image1 = '1', 'C:/folder/subfolder', image1),
        image2 = IF(image2 = '1', 'C:/folder/subfolder', image2),
        image3 = IF(image3 = '1', 'C:/folder/subfolder', image3),
        ...
WHERE '1' IN (image1, image2, image3, ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

The *WHERE* clause might be what you need in your SQL. Something like:

```
UPDATE images SET image1="C:/folder/subfolder" WHERE image1="1";
```

Might not be the full answer, but I thought this might help on the right path.

Comment: You'll need to repeat that statement for each column.