# How can I update a row only if a select query returns one row?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to check if two user supplied values match a row in the database, and if they do, change an enum value from 0 to 1.

I know I can do this in two queries, but I'd rather do it in one. The only thing I've been ale to find is how to update a row if it exists, and create it if it doesn't. However, I don't want this, as if the supplied values are incorrect the script should exit.

Can I use `IF EXISTS (SELECT x FROM x where y = y AND z = z) UPDATE ...`

Will this work? And if so, how can I check if it executed within PHP?

Comment: i think your over complicating this see below

Answer (score 3):

I think you would just use `where` with `update`:

```
update x
    set enumcol = 1
    where y = $y and z = $z;
```

This updates rows where values match.  If no rows match, then no rows are updated.

Comment: hmm, I should have thought of this. How can I know if it was executed correctly however?

Comment: @cantsay mysqli_affected_rows

Answer (score 2):

Wouldnt that just be done with a standard condition? Like:

```
UPDATE my_table 
SET enum_field=1 
WHERE one_field=[first_value] AND another_field=[second_value]
```

Maybe you also would have to match against a user ID or something:

```
UPDATE my_table 
SET enum_field=1 
WHERE one_field=[first_value] AND another_field=[second_value] AND id=[user_id]
```

In more complex cases this answer might help:

[MySQL: update a field only if condition is met](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14893355/mysql-update-a-field-only-if-condition-is-met)