# INSERT INTO column if column = null

Tags: mysql

how to insert into column value if column =NULL 
I have table 'board' with column 'name' some column has value , some has value NULL , I need insert in all column where is value = NULL

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL: update a field only if condition is met](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14893355/mysql-update-a-field-only-if-condition-is-met)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you need to update instead of insert.

If your value could also be a "NULL" value of type String then this might help

```
UPDATE board
SET name = 'value_to_be_inserted'
WHERE name IS NULL and upper(name) != "NULL"
```

Comment: Why `upper(name) != "NULL"`?

Comment: If the value of null entered in the table is a string then "IS NULL" might miss...

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to *insert*, you need to *update*:

```
UPDATE board
SET name = 'some value'
WHERE name IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an other perspective with `CASE` expression.

**Query**

```
update `board`
set `name` = (
    case when `name` is null then 'new value'
    else `name` end
);
```