# How to modify the value of a unique index

Tags: mysql, indexing, unique

```
CREATE TABLE `entityfeedhot` (
  `efhid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '主键ID',
  `idx` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'order num',
  `age` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `gender` tinyint(4) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT '，1：man，2：famal',
  `deleteflag` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`efhid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idx_age_gender_deleteflag` (`idx`,`age`,`gender`,`deleteflag`),
  KEY `efid` (`efid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=916 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ;
```

now  I want to make idx=idx-1 in  eg. range(idx>1 AND idx<9 )

but due to  UNIQUE KEY `idx_age_gender_deleteflag`  I have an error

```
 Duplicate entry '4-0-1-0' for key 'idx_age_gender_deleteflag'
```

I want to know the best way to let  idx=id-1 or idx=id+1

Comment: To possibly state the obvious: You want all the new values of your unique index to be `value - 1` ?

Comment: idx is order number, change the order num  for each year under one gender

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Three Methods - Method 1 is preferred:

1) Cycle through each entry and remove 1 from that entry value, starting at the lowest and working up.

```
UPDATE `entityfeedhot` SET `idx` = `idx` - 1 WHERE `idx` > 1 AND `idx` < 9 ORDER BY `idx` ASC
```

The `ORDER BY`clause is important as it ensures that rows are processed in ascending order, to avoid result duplicates. `idx = 1` should not exist.

---

2) Make a new column such as `idx_two` and set this column value to equal idx - 1. This negates the index's unique status (because it's a new column).

```
ALTER TABLE `entityfeedhot` ADD `new_dx` INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' AFTER `idx`;
```

Then populate the column:

```
UPDATE `entityfeedhot` SET `new_dx` = CASE
WHEN  `idx` > 1 AND `idx` < 9 THEN `idx` = `idx` - 1
ELSE `idx`
```

The above query will populate with idx - 1 [where the `WHEN` condition is true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14893355/mysql-update-a-field-only-if-condition-is-met), else it will just copy the value. All rows will be updated.

Then delete the idx column and rename the new column. Indxes will need to be rebuilt.

---

3) Turn off your unique status of your index.

Make your changes

Turn back on the unique status of your index.

Comment: Thank you very much, I feel so stupid, I will try every method.

Comment: @Allenwong don't feel stupid, it's always easier once you know the answer. Happy to help!